# How can I use React Router to nest some routes? And I want to keep a header component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

I have a stepper component at the top and a next/back button at the bottom. All I want is to change the route but I want to keep those 2 components there. Look:

[image]

That thing within the red rectangle is what I need to change. I want to the rest just as it is.

This is what I have in the App.js so far:

```
const App = () => (
  <ReduxProvider store={store}>
    <Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Navbar />

        <div className="App-container">
          <Route exact path="/signup" component={SignupPage} />
          <Route exact path="/startup-application"
            component={StartupApplication}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
  </ReduxProvider>
);

export default App;
```

Where `/startup-application` is the route where I want to nest my other routes. The nested routes will be like -> `/startup-application/step-one`, `/startup-application/step-two` and so on.

Comment: You would need to put your router inside the component which contains that Red color section

Comment: You just want to add nested routes inside `StartupApplication` component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the nested `Routes` inside the component where you want it to render. Here, you want to render nested `Routes` inside the `StartupApplication` component. so you can do following

```
 function StartupApplication({match}) {
      return (
        <div>
          <h2>StartupApplication</h2>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to={`${match.url}/step-one`}>Step One</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to={`${match.url}/step-two`}>Step Two</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
          // adding the nested routes
          <Route path={`${match.path}/:nestedComponent`} component={StepOne} />
          <Route path={`${match.path}/:nestedComponent`} component={StepTwo} />
        </div>
      );
    }
```

For more information on nested routes, you can go to [source](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic).